# Play/animate images, spritesheets or video files in 'template_icon_view'

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I want to "play" some animation in this UI space, the  `template_icon_view`:

[image]

I can load all the images I want, for example:

[image]

I know that the gif format is not available.

I know the files with video format (.wmv, .mp4, .avi), can not be played, right?

Then I tested with sprite-sheet, but I can't select or split in each "frame":

[image]
[image]

Then I create operator that allow me change the image, but manually:

```
actual = wm["my_previews"] 
total =wm["my_previews"] 
contar=True
while contar:
    wm["my_previews"] = wm["my_previews"] +1
    if wm.my_previews == "":
        contar = False
    else:
        total +=1

wm["my_previews"] = wm["my_previews"] 
if avanzar and actual <total:         
    wm["my_previews"] = actual +1            
elif (avanzar and actual == total):
    wm["my_previews"] = 0
elif avanzar==False and actual>0:
    wm["my_previews"] = actual -1
elif (avanzar==False and actual==0):
    wm["my_previews"] =total
```

[image]

But I can not do this automatically, because I can not update the `template_icon_view` and all my tries crash blender.

I try with time, thread:

```
while Play:
    
    wm["my_previews"] = wm["my_previews"] +1
   
    if wm.my_previews == "":
        wm["my_previews"] =0
        Play = False
    
    time.sleep(0.5)

z = threading.Thread(target=self.testplay(C, self.Play))
if self.Play:
    z.start()
else:
    z.stop()
```

I checked the Update options in different part of code and nothing works

```
bpy.context.view_layer.update()
dg =bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
dg.update()
```

Any ideas? Maybe I'm in the wrong UI space to achieve my goal?

Actually, I was thinking of loading some blender files with the animations, but also I can't play that in the `template_icon_view`.

Comment: Must it be looped endlessly?

Comment: @NoobCat I thought the same,  but the blender interface is frozen until the process is finished

Comment: You can create a separate thread for it. That is how game engines work.

Comment: I Don't want it for GE @Bruk. Actually do yo have Some code example?

Comment: @yhoyo I was just saying game engines use that method they calculate physics and other stuff while animating. The reason blender's UI froze is because it have to finish drawing before it can update and since you are running an infinite loop it will never update thus it froze. If you call animate function which update the image and set a timer to call  it based upon the frame rate of your animation you can get it working. Here is a link to about timers https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/#timer.